# VSCode Unable to import 'example' pylint(import-error)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am getting pylint errors in VSCode that say they are unable to import local files. However, I am able to run the files through the debugger with no problem. I thought that pylint used the same PYTHONPATH that the interpreter uses, so I don't know why this is happening.

I have my code set up like so:

```
dir0
-dir1
--__init__.py
--src
---__init__.py
---srcdir1
----__init__.py
----file1.py
---srcdir2
----__init__.py
----file2.py
```

file1.py looks like this:

```
def func1():
    return 1
```

file2.py looks like this:

```
from srcdir1.file1 import func1
func1()
```

in launch.json I have:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "/full/path/to/dir0/dir1/src:/usr/local/bin/python"}
```

Pylint is giving me an import error around "from srcdir1.file1". When I go into the debugger and click run debugger, the file runs with no issues. However, if I right click and select Run Code, I get import errors that match the pylint errors.

EDIT:
I created a file in my workspace folder called `.env` in my workspace folder. It is as follows:

```
PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/Users/user/path/dir0/dir1/src:/Users/user/path/client/src:/Users/user/path/product/src
```

Interestingly, I can import from product (the third in the list) but not from client. Is there somewhere that this environment is being overridden?

I also have the following in the file:

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
```

For some reason, `import sys` (but not the others) gives me the following error: `unresolved import 'sys'Python(unresolved-import)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `__init__.py` files inside those folders? Otherwise python won't recognise them as modules and will be unable to import the code. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/5015356 for more information

Comment: Yes, there are `__init__.py` files in all the folders.

Comment: After Python 3.6 there no need for init files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you specified a `PYTHONPATH` for the debugger and not the general extension to send to Pylint. Try setting `PYTHONPATH` in a [`.env` environment variable definition file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file).

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting an error. I edited my post to include more information. Could you take a look?

Comment: Two things. One, `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` in `PYTHONPATH` is redundant as Python will add that to `sys.path` automatically. Two, your question about `client/` is hard to answer as you didn't share any details about another directory that you were trying to import from and didn't provide the layout details, etc.