# Pylint in VSCode goes mad when importing third-party moudles installed with pipenv by throwing no-member errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I've got a pipenv virtualenv. I've added it to workplace settings:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/home/keddad/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-8gFlsF9b/bin/python",
```

It works, more or less. It starts a terminal in the pipenv by default, and it works flawlessly when I work with built-in modules. But if I install a module with pipenv, it starts working somehow strange. Let's say I've installed pydantic, import it and use like this:

```
import pydantic
class Foo(pydantic.BaseModel):
    bar: str
```

If I just run it, it works. Hinting in editor also works. But pylint marks this code as an error:

```
Module 'pydantic' has no 'BaseModel' member pylint(no-member)
```

Same thing happens if I just do

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
```

I've tried creating an .env file in project directory to specify `PYTHONPATH` in it like in one of the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784306/vscode-unable-to-import-example-pylintimport-error) question, but it didn't really help. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a workaround, one might try using another linter. `flake8` works fine, for example